# How to get values from multiple form field values using Array.from and forEach

Tags: javascript, html, forms, foreach, getelementsbyclassname

Lets say I have a form:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" class="blanked">
  <input type="text" class="blanked">
  <input type="text" class="blanked">
  <input type="submit" value="Press Me">
</form>
```

Now lets say I use `getElementsByClassName` to create an array of these elements:

`let filledBlanks = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName( 'blanked' ));`

Now I want to iterate through the values the user has entered into each input:

```
filledBlanks.forEach( filledBlank => {
  let inputText = filledBlank.???;
}
```

This is where I get tripped up. What do I use to get the filled value (not .value)? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why would it not be `filledBlank.value`?

Comment: *"What do I use to get the filled value (not `.value`)"* Why?

Comment: You can use `innerHTML` for this

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback. .value wasn't working for me initially, which is why I said not .value above...but after hearing that it should work I went back and realized my JS was running when the page initially loaded and not with the onclock event thus why value had been returning empty values for me previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `.value` property works just fine. I don't see why you would need something else.
If you want to only iterate over the values, you could map your input first, but i don't see the point.

Please note here that i'm only using Jquery to listen to the `submit` event. The rest is pure vanilla Javascript.

```js
$('form').on('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  let filledBlanks = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName( 'blanked' ));
  filledBlanks.map((input) => {
    return input.value;
  }).forEach((value) => {
    console.log(value);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="blanked">
  <input type="text" class="blanked">
  <input type="text" class="blanked">
  <input type="submit" value="Press Me" id="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. As I mention in the comments above, the issue was elsewhere in my code. I had the JS outside of a function and it was running on page load rather than after the submit button had been click, so it was always returning empty...thus why I thought value didn't work.